# Python - highlight pattern inside a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I have a simple exam to pass where I have to write a program where I create a binary matrix and a pattern and I have to find the pattern inside the matrix and to highlight it if found. I can't use any external library - specially numpy.

What I have atm are just some highlighted numbers that don't match my pattern. I don't know how to continue. Can someone help me please?

My code is this:

pattern.py:

```html
# to create a matrix from an array of arrays
def create(n, m, data):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(n): #n=rows number
        row = []
        for j in range(m): #m=columns number
            if data[j] not in matrix:
                row.append(data[m * i + j])
        matrix.append(row)
    return matrix


# to colour the elements in 1 inside the pattern
def colora(element):
    if element == 1:
        element = '\u001b[36m1'
    elif element == 0:
        element = '\u001b[00m0'
    return element

# my pattern forms an I vertically - I should also find it if horizontal
def patternI():
    array = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
    pattern = create(3, 3, array)
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            col_element = colora(pattern[i][j])
            print(col_element, end=" ")
            # print(pattern[i][j], end=" ")
        print()
    return pattern
```

main.py:

```html
import patterns
import ricerca

# to create and print the matrix
def matrix():
    m = 5
    n = 5
    array = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
    matrix = patterns.create(n, m, array)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            print(matrix[i][j], end=" ")
        print()
    return matrix



def main():
    print("pattern:")
    pattern = patterns.patternI()
    print("\r")

    print("matrix:")
    matrice = matrix()
    print("\r")

    print("risult:")
    newArray=ricerca.ricerca(pattern, matrice)




main()
```

ricerca.py:

```html
import patterns

# to search the pattern (m_piccola) inside the (m_grande)
def ricerca(m_piccola, m_grande) :
    daricordare = [] #an array to fill with the position of the matrix which combines a little with the pattern
    for jR in range(len(m_piccola) - 1) :
        for iR in range(len(m_grande)) :
            for iC in range(len(m_grande[0])) :
                for jC in range(len(m_piccola[jR])) :
                    if m_piccola[jR][jC] == 0 :
                        jC += 1
                        break
                    if m_piccola[jR][jC] == 1 :
                        if m_grande[iR][iC] == m_piccola[jR][jC] :
                            daricordare.append((iR, iC))
                        else :
                            iC += 1
    data = coloraQuelliDelPattern(daricordare, m_grande)
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            print(data[i][j], end = " ")
        print()
    return data


# to highlight the numbers in the array which are inside "daricordare"
def coloraQuelliDelPattern(daricordare, array) :

    for i in range(len(daricordare) - 2) :
        a = daricordare[i]
        b = daricordare[i + 1]
        c = daricordare[i + 2]
        if b[1] == a[1] + 1  and c[1]==a[1] + 2:
            array[a[0]][a[1]] = "\u001b[36m1"
            array[b[0]][b[1]] = "\u001b[36m1"
            array[c[0]][c[1]] = "\u001b[36m1"
        if b[1] != a[1] + 1 or c[1] != a[1] + 2 :
            array[a[0]][a[1]] = "\u001b[00m1"
            array[b[0]][b[1]] = "\u001b[00m1"
            array[c[0]][c[1]] = "\u001b[00m1"

    return array
```

Comment: Is the pattern always the same? Are you searching for an "I" or could be any pattern?

Comment: @itogaston the pattern is the same (it’s a one-time game). The pattern can be anything: a T, an I, a C… the point is that once it’s defined, we have to find the match in the matrix.